# I have a problem using a transfer function in my smart contract solidity 0.4.16

Tags: solidity

So basically, I want a transfer function of ERC20 tokens on 0.4.16, but I want to make it so that you can specify which token you want to transfer to another address, but everytime I try to send tokens, there's an error, I think it's because the "msg.sender" has to approve the tokens, but idk, this is the code, if you want to review it:

```
pragma solidity 0.4.16;

interface ERC20 {
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool);
}

contract TokenTransfer {
    function transferToken(address _tokenAddress, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
        // Create an instance of the ERC20 token contract
        ERC20 token = ERC20(_tokenAddress);

        // Transfer the specified amount of tokens to the specified address
        return token.transfer(_to, _value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Things that would help:
1. put the code in code-blocks so that it is easier to read
2. include the error you have (compile error / runtime error)

Comment: With that code, you would be sending tokens from the balance of the contract to the _to address, so there would be no problems with approvals. Maybe it does not have balance to send.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`transfer()` would transfer tokens that are already in your contract to `_to`, and is gonna fail if your contract doesn't have the required balance. If you want to take tokens from the user calling `transferToken()`, you'll need to use transferFrom(), and in that case you're going to need approval, yes.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, I just needed to add some tokens to the contract, btw, can you help me with my other question about BatchTransfer?